# How to order a grid vertically in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a simple grid layout in Bootstrap 5 like this:

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-lg-3">
    <div class="col border">Field1</div>
    <div class="col border">Field2</div>
    <div class="col border">Field3</div>
    <div class="col border">Field4</div>
    <div class="col border">Field5</div>
    <div class="col border">Field6</div>
    <div class="col border">Field7</div>
    <div class="col border">Field8</div>
    <div class="col border">Field9</div>
</div>
```

Depending on the screen width, it looks like this:

```
Large                Medium         Small
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]    [ 1 ] [ 2 ]    [ 1 ] 
[ 4 ] [ 5 ] [ 6 ]    [ 3 ] [ 4 ]    [ 2 ] 
[ 7 ] [ 8 ] [ 9 ]    [ 5 ] [ 6 ]    [ 3 ]
                     [ 7 ] [ 8 ]    [ 4 ]
                     [ 9 ]          [ 5 ]
                                    ...
```

However, I want it to be ordered vertically:

```
Large                Medium         Small
[ 1 ] [ 4 ] [ 7 ]    [ 1 ] [ 6 ]    [ 1 ] 
[ 2 ] [ 5 ] [ 8 ]    [ 2 ] [ 7 ]    [ 2 ] 
[ 3 ] [ 6 ] [ 9 ]    [ 3 ] [ 8 ]    [ 3 ]
                     [ 4 ] [ 9 ]    [ 4 ]
                     [ 5 ]          [ 5 ]
                                    ...
```

A solution I found is to use the `order` class depending on the screen width, like:

```
<div class="col border order-4 order-sm-7 order-lg-2">Field4</div>
```

This seams to be a mass and error prone, if a field es added in the future.

Is this the way to go, or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: You need to switch the row from `flex-flow: row` to `flex-flow: column` Then you might also need to add some kind of "breakpoint" for when a second column should start. Didn't use bootstrap for this ever, but using column instead of row should be the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom class on the parent element and with the additional CSS property `column-count` and two breakpoints to reduce the `column-count`. Also remove the **row** class from the parent element.

```css
.column-order {
  --count: 3;
  column-count: var(--count);
  column-gap: 0;
}

.column-order>div {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .column-order {
    --count: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .column-order {
    --count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="column-order">
  <div class="col border">Field1</div>
  <div class="col border">Field2</div>
  <div class="col border">Field3</div>
  <div class="col border">Field4</div>
  <div class="col border">Field5</div>
  <div class="col border">Field6</div>
  <div class="col border">Field7</div>
  <div class="col border">Field8</div>
  <div class="col border">Field9</div>
  <div class="col border">Field10</div>
  <div class="col border">Field11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for the nine fields. However, this breaks, if I add a 10th field in the future (see question).

Comment: It works! Am I right, that the `row-col-x` classes are no longer needed?

Comment: You can also remove them.